# How to reposition view using swift in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, autolayout

I am using story board to build ui for my application and uses swift & i have prepared below layout you can see in screen shot.
[image]

I want to hide view containing details of stop1 & place stop2 view in place of stop1 at runtime.

I am using following code to hide stop1 & update constraint of stop2

```
    stop1Frame.hidden = true
    stop2Frame.updateConstraints()
```

Please help me.

putting height constraint to 0 of stop1 worked but shows me below error in console.

```
 2015-03-13 17:03:52.738 GroundSpan[5392:1777378] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)
    (
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a644500 V:[UILabel:0x7a643d50'Please tap on + button to...'(63)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a64cb80 V:[UIView:0x7a63aaa0(0)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a64cc10 UILabel:0x7a632e20'Stop1'.top == UIView:0x7a63aaa0.topMargin>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a64d2b0 V:[UILabel:0x7a643d50'Please tap on + button to...']-(20)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7a63aaa0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a64d310 V:[UILabel:0x7a632e20'Stop1']-(NSSpace(8))-[UILabel:0x7a643d50'Please tap on + button to...']>")

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 

<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a644500 V:[UILabel:0x7a643d50'Please tap on + button to...'(63)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-03-13 17:03:52.739 GroundSpan[5392:1777378] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a64cb80 V:[UIView:0x7a63aaa0(0)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a64cc10 UILabel:0x7a632e20'Stop1'.top == UIView:0x7a63aaa0.topMargin>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a64d2b0 V:[UILabel:0x7a643d50'Please tap on + button to...']-(20)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7a63aaa0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a64d310 V:[UILabel:0x7a632e20'Stop1']-(NSSpace(8))-[UILabel:0x7a643d50'Please tap on + button to...']>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a64d310 V:[UILabel:0x7a632e20'Stop1']-(NSSpace(8))-[UILabel:0x7a643d50'Please tap on + button to...']>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: Where is your Swift code ?

Comment: swift code added that i use to hide and update constraint

Answer (score 3):

Create an `IBOutlet` to the height constraint of stop1 so you can access it in your code.

To hide stop1, set its height constraint to 0, so stop2 will move up.

```
@IBOutlet weak var stop1HeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
...

// in your function:
self.stop1HeightConstraint.constant = 0

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

This all assumes that you have setup your autolayout and constraints correctly.

Comment: Your trick make the stop2 to reposition in place of stop1 but gives error in console please look edited question for error log.

Comment: That's what I meant in the last sentence of my answer: Your constraints need to be setup correctly. We cannot see how you set the constraints. The white boxes should be UIViews and the labels and buttons in them should be positioned relative to that parent view.

Comment: I didnt see any red or yellow line Every thing is perfectly in blue that means all constraints are set up pretty well.
But still getting this msg.